# How To Combine These Two Less @Media Queries With An "Or" Condition?

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design, less, media-queries

Suppose I have some less code like this:

```
@desktop-min-width:         1024px;
@phone-max-width:           768px;

@desktop:          ~"only screen and (min-width: @{desktop-min-width})";
@tablet:           ~"only screen and (min-width: @{phone-max-width}) and (max-width: @{desktop-min-width})";
@phone:            ~"only screen and (max-width: @{phone-max-width})";

.hola {

  @phone {
    height: 100vh;
    top:    10px;
  }

  @tablet {
    height: 30vh;
    top:    30%;
  }

  @desktop {
    height: 30vh;
    top:    30%;
  }

}

// ...more styles...
```

I there a way for me to combine the @tablet and @desktop and reduce the duplication? Something like this is what I'm imagining:

```
@tablet or @desktop {
  height: 30vh;
  top:    30%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using a comma should do what you want:

```
@tablet, @desktop  {
  ...
}
```